# Should I use ./ or index.html for the hyperlink reference on my 'home' links?

Tags: html

I have a website with a 'home' link like many do and I am wondering whether I should do:

`<a href="./">Home</a>`

or

`<a href="index.html">Home</a>`

Obviously my homepage is contained in the index.html file. I have the first option implemented right now and it seems to work, but I am not sure what the preferred practice is or if there are any drawbacks to one or the other.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `href="/"` may require the browser to submit *two* requests. The first to `"/"` which is redirected at the server to `"index.html"`.  If it's not a 302 redirect, then there may be some potential search indexing implications, though that's subjective voodoo that may not apply.

The other issue is if your server just returns the contents of `index.html` for `"/"`. When that is true your site will have two different URLs for the same resource. Not having canonical URLs for the same reference *will* affect your search performance.

While linking to `"/"` may offer some flexibility in that you can change it in the future, the difference between `index.html` and `index.php` is usually a significant architectural change and "future proofing" against is pointless. If you're switching to a dynamic site in the future, you'll be updating all your home links anyway...so no need to optimize for what won't ever happen.

Answer (score 3):

Of the two `href="/index.html"` is the better choice. `href="./"` will not work reliable because of the dot.

`href="/"` is the most flexible because it allows you to change to a different index page (index.php, index.asp, etc) later without updating your code.

Comment: I like being explicit. If the page changes later, then I think there should be an error to remind the programmer to change it. Not all web servers replace / with /index.html.

Comment: But most does and changing server config in a single place is easier than replacing various links if you changed something. Relative paths should always be considered as the better way.

Comment: Actually `href="./"` has been working beautifully so far, the only reason I thought there might be an issue is because when I was editing in Aptana I clicked the home link in preview mode and it displayed the folder rather than the index.html page.

Comment: @tjameson: I agree that ambiguity should be avoided. But do you agree that explicitly setting the target of '/' to be '/index.html' (for example) in one place (the webserver configuration) is preferable to setting it in several places in the code?

Comment: @Treebranch: The relative-path reference ('./') will work as long as your site pages are only a single later deep. However, if you eventually use subfolders (ie: '/sub/folder/page.html') a reference to './' will point to '/sub/folder/' rather than your home page.

Comment: @Jay: `index.html` is just as relative as `./`. the question isn't related to relative vs absolute paths, rather if it's best to rely on the convention that requesting a folder returns the default document for that folder.

Comment: @Treebranch- Well, `./` should work, but it will get the index.html at the current directory. Say you're in `/feature/doc.html`, `./` will try to get `/feature/index.html`, and if that's not defined, then you'd get a 404.

Comment: @George Cummins- For example, with node.js, there is no config file. Either use a framework or do it yourself. I would advise doing it explicitly always just in case you switch webservers and forget to adjust the config file.